# Empty <f:selectItems > in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf-2, glassfish, facelets, managed-bean

I am using JSF 2.0 facelets and i am tring to get the selected items value from a database, I tried the @PostConstruct way but it throws an excpetion, I will write everything shortly,

I tried the same databse connection and entities and it runs good.

I should also mention that here i am using string to send to selectItems, and before i used SelectItem List but it also did not work,

And The funny thing was that when I inserted a try and catch block in the while loop(u'll see in a moment) by mistake, it threw the exception but over and over again, which means that the list is not empty, but its just not getting to the page.

What Cloud be the cause of that ?

My jsf code

```
<h:selectOneMenu >
  <f:selectItems value="#{settingsBean.countryItems}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

my managed bean

```
@Named(value = "settingsBean")
```

@RequestScoped
public class SettingsBean {

```
/**
 * Creates a new instance of SettingsBean
 */
 private String favorits;
private String hobbies;
private String aboutme;
private String education;
private String country;
private String listCountry;
private List<String> countryItems;
private List<Countries> countries;

@EJB
CountriesFacadeLocal cin = new CountriesFacade();


public SettingsBean() {

}
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    countries = cin.getAll();
    if(!countries.isEmpty())
    {
        int i =0;
        ListIterator iterator = countries.listIterator();
      while(iterator.hasNext())
      {
          listCountry = countries.get(i).getCountry();
            countryItems.add(i, listCountry);
      }                    
    }
}
```

my CountriesFacadeCode

```
@Override
    public List<Countries> getAll()
    {
        try{
        em.flush();
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Countries.findAll");
        List<Countries> countryList = query.getResultList();
        if(countryList!= null)
        {
            return countryList;
        }
        else
            return null;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

my stackTrace

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method] @PostConstruct public com.readme.user.signup.SettingsBean.init() on com.readme.user.signup.SettingsBean@606e86
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:595)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:200)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:340)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:87)
    at com.readme.user.signup.org$jboss$weld$bean-web-ManagedBean-class_com$readme$user$signup$SettingsBean_$$_WeldClientProxy.getFavorits(org$jboss$weld$bean-web-ManagedBean-class_com$readme$user$signup$SettingsBean_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:55)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:305)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:299)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:193)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:591)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.readme.user.signup.SettingsBean.init(SettingsBean.java:56)
    ... 76 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause is a NullPointerException in SettingsBean line 56.
I don't know whats written in this line, but inspecting your code, it could be that the class variable `countryItems` was never initialized.

Comment: @Developer106: you're not understanding the answer. You've declared `countryItems` as a class variable `private List<String> countryItems;`, but this has a default value of `null`. You need to initialize it with `new ArrayList<String>()` or something. Any methods which you attempt to invoke on a `null` reference will throw `NullPointerException`, like as the `add()` method did.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix up EJB Annotation with new 
as 
CountriesFacadeLocal cin = new CountriesFacade();
In case you have decided to use use Container logic as EJB you should stick to this. Otherwise your field isn't initialized at all (neither EJB nor new) and therfore null.